# ForceUpdateSize ListView issue on iOS

Tags: ios, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

I have a custom ListView using custom ViewCells with radio buttons. On clicking of each of the radio buttons the ListView dynamically resizes its height to hide/show a comment box.

On using `ForceUpdateSize` in iOS platform, the ListView performance slows down rapidly on clicking the radio buttons. The app eventually hangs and stops responding.

Is there an alternative solution to use instead of `ForceUpdateSize` to dynamically expand the ListView row at runtime?

Comment: Removed tags from title; trademark capitalization; noise reduction.

Comment: The documentation even says that this can be an expensive operation: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Cell.ForceUpdateSize()/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Define a ViewCell Size Change event wherever you need to change your ViewCell size

```
public static event Action ViewCellSizeChangedEvent;
```

In your case, it should be triggered by your radio button. Call it like this:

```
ViewCellSizeChangedEvent?.Invoke();
```

It will then use the ListView renderer to update the iOS TableView.

```
public class CustomListViewRenderer : ListViewRenderer
{
    public CustomListViewRenderer()
    {
        WhatEverContentView.ViewCellSizeChangedEvent += UpdateTableView;
    }

    private void UpdateTableView()
    {
        var tv = Control as UITableView;
        if (tv == null) return;
        tv.BeginUpdates();
        tv.EndUpdates();
    }
}
```

It should solve your performance problem while keep using your Xaml instead of creating a custom ViewCell which is not needed.

Comment: Can you explain why `BeginUpdates` and `EndUpdates` fix the performance problem? I thought they were being used for cell animations.

Comment: I can't tell for sure, but the standard xamarin.ios cell-resizing appears to be animated. When I make changes to the size the viewcell animates a linear collapsing/expanding by default

Comment: OMG you cannot imagine how much time I spent checking around for this. Nothing worked, until I saw this. Phew, thanks Duke. Btw, if you don't want to use a static event, you can set a new property like `NeedsLayout` or anything which gets called in the renderer's `OnElementPropertyChanged()`-method.

Comment: Thank you a thousand times for this! We were seeing random run-time crashes related to our use of ForceUpdateSize. This solution saved me from untold pain and anguish.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is: Try to use custom renderer. When the button clicked, I use tableView.ReloadRows() to dynamically change the size of a cell.

Firstly, define a bool list whose items equal to Rows you want to show in the Source. I initialize its items with false at first time.

```
List<bool> isExpanded = new List<bool>();

public MyListViewSource(MyListView view)
{
    //It depends on how many rows you want to show.
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) 
    {
        isExpanded.Add(false);
    }
}
```

Secondly, Construct the GetCell event(I just put a UISwitch in my Cell for testing) like:

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{

    MyListViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell("Cell") as MyListViewCell;

    if (cell == null)
    {
        cell = new MyListViewCell(new NSString("Cell"));

        //This event is constructed in my Cell, when the switch's value changed it will be fired.
        cell.RefreshEvent += (refreshCell, isOn) =>
        {
            NSIndexPath index = tableView.IndexPathForCell(refreshCell);
            isExpanded[index.Row] = isOn;
            tableView.ReloadRows(new NSIndexPath[] { index }, UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic);
        };
    }

    cell.switchBtn.On = isExpanded[indexPath.Row];

    return cell;
}
```

At last, we can override the GetHeightForRow event. Set a large or small value depending on the item in the isExpanded:

```
public override nfloat GetHeightForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    if (isExpanded[indexPath.Row])
    {
        return 80;
    }
    return 40;
}
```

Here is some part of my cell for you referring to:

```
//When switch's value changed, this event will be called
public delegate void RefreshHanle(MyListViewCell cell, bool isOn);
public event RefreshHanle RefreshEvent;
switchBtn.AddTarget((sender, args) =>
{
    UISwitch mySwitch = sender as UISwitch;
    RefreshEvent(this, mySwitch.On);
}, UIControlEvent.ValueChanged);
```

Comment: my listview is a cross platform control. It works perfectly fine in android. Can  this above solution be applied to ios custom listview renderer?

Comment: @Apurva19 Yep，I made a renderer for listview to do this.

Comment: @ Land Thanks, il try out your solution and post back.

Comment: @ Land  Can you tell me where does that RefreshEvent event handler code which u have given should be added. I m slight confused with it. In my case i have used radio button images binded to commands in view model.

Comment: @Apurva19 I create this refresh event in my custom cell, when the toggle button’s value changes it will be called. If you are still confused about it, I can make a sample for you.

Comment: @Apurva19 I made a simple sample [here](https://github.com/lt0526/ListViewDemo) in iOS renderer. Each cell has a switch controlling the cell's height.

Comment: Lu - Hi i finally used the default listview and fixed the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please provide the definition of MyListViewCell as well?